# Incorrect parameter count in the call nativeFunction 'DATEDIFF'

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am trying to get the difference of the current date and the due date that is saved in the Mysql Database and it will save to the Mysql as penalty column. But the error says that

> 'incorrect parameter count in the call native Function DATEDIFF'

. Ive been searching answers for 5hrs. but nothing matched on my case. This is stopping my project to get done.

```
     Dim Query2 As String
        Query2 = "select datediff(dd,curdate(),due_date) from periodicals AS penalty where student_id like '%" & TextBox2.Text & "%'"
        COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query2, MysqlConn)
        SDA.SelectCommand = COMMAND
        SDA.Fill(dbDataSet)
        bSource.DataSource = dbDataSet
        DataGridView1.DataSource = bSource
        SDA.Update(dbDataSet)
```

Comment: I guess you need to use `TIMESTAMPDIFF(dd,curdate(),due_date)` instead of `datediff(dd,curdate(),due_date)` so the query should be `Query2 = "select TIMESTAMPDIFF(dd,curdate(),due_date)  from periodicals AS penalty where student_id like '%" & TextBox2.Text & "%'"`,Just try it !!

Comment: doesnt work for me sir.

Comment: im having a syntax error sir.

Comment: @G.Vister You should be aware that you need to consult the documentation for MySQL rather than T-SQL - many, if not all, databases have slight variations in their version of SQL.

Answer (score 2):

In [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) needs only two parameters:

```
DATEDIFF(expr1,expr2)
```

`DATEDIFF()` returns `expr1 − expr2` expressed as a value in days from one date to the other. expr1 and expr2 are date or date-and-time expressions. Only the date parts of the values are used in the calculation.

So you can use:

```
DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), due_date)
```

Comment: in here it displays '' select datediff(curdate(),due_date)"